# Adding multiple wp_register_scripts for templates in WordPres?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

How do I add multiple JavaScript files to templates?

The below works great for only ONE Javascript file which loads on the templates called template-1.php and template-2.php - but I have another 3 JavaScript files.

```
  // Template ABC
  if ( is_page_template( array('template-1.php','template-2.php'))):
    wp_register_script( 'Name of JS File', 'https://url.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('Name of JS File');
  endif;
```

Would the below be the correct approach if I wanted to add the other Javascript files to the same templates?

```
  // Template ABC
  if ( is_page_template( array('template-1.php','template-2.php'))):
    wp_register_script( 'Name of JS File', 'https://url.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'Name of NEW JS File 1', 'https://url-new-1.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'Name of NEW JS File 2', 'https://url-new-2.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('Name of JS File');
  endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's a better practice to merge all your JS files in a single JavaScript and enqueue it to reduce HTTP requests, it's alright to enqueue them separately too. So, you can register the script ( not required ) and then enqueue it.

Just enqueue all of the scripts after registering them, like:

```
  // Template ABC
  if ( is_page_template( array('template-1.php','template-2.php'))):

    wp_register_script( 'Name of JS File', 'https://url.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'Name of NEW JS File 1', 'https://url-new-1.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'Name of NEW JS File 2', 'https://url-new-2.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script('Name of JS File');
    wp_enqueue_script('Name of JS File 1');
    wp_enqueue_script('Name of JS File 2');
  endif;
```

Or directly enqueue them all:

```
  // Template ABC
  if ( is_page_template( array('template-1.php','template-2.php'))):

    wp_enqueue_script( 'Name of JS File', 'https://url.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Name of NEW JS File 1', 'https://url-new-1.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Name of NEW JS File 2', 'https://url-new-2.js' );

  endif;
```